# Why am I receiving an invalid syntax error for this code to make a plot using plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I have two data frames (gyeEUR and gyeEMR) wit incident cases per 100k measured in different countries by year.  I am looking to make 2 side by side scatter plots in plotly with year on the x axis and incident cases per 100k on the y axis and different colored lines for the different countries.  I am using the following code:

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=gyeEMR["year"], y=gyeEMR["incident cases per 100k", color=gyeEMR["country"]], row=1, col=1
)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=gyeEUR["year"], y=gyeEUR["incident cases per 100k"], color=gyeEUR["country"]),
    row=2, col=1
)

fig.update_layout(height=600, width=800)
fig.show()
```

This code has been returning an invalid syntax error  for fig.add_trace and I don't understand why.  Could someone point me towards what I am doing wrong?

Edit:  Here is the error

[image]

Edit:  Here is the gyeEMR dataframe

[image]

Comment: Could you show the full error please?

Answer (score 3):

You one missing one paranthesis in the first `add_trace`:

```
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=gyeEMR["year"], y=gyeEMR["incident cases per 100k"], color=gyeEMR["country"], row=1, col=1))
```

Comment: Thank you.  That fixed the invalid syntax error, but now I am receiving another error.  ValueError: Invalid properties specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Scatter: ('color', 'row', 'col')

Comment: go.Scatter() dont take `color, row, col` as argument. I´m not 100% sure about this but the ValueError indicate this.what are you trying to do? your go.scatter objet seems little bit off.